# Why flushing output buffer before printing char array doesn't print garbage data?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, buffer, flush

When printing a char array directly I get garbage data printed out with it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char x [5] {'H','E','L','L','O'};
    cout << "Output : ";
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0; }
```

`Output : HELLO@ ~`

But, this doesn't happen when I flush the output buffer before printing the char array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char x [5] {'H','E','L','L','O'};
    cout << "Output : " << flush;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0; }
```

`Output : HELLO`

However, I don't see this behaviour if I don't print anything before flushing output buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char x [5] {'H','E','L','L','O'};
    cout << flush;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0; }
```

`Output : HELLO}~`

The char array in all of the above examples doesn't have the `'\0'` escape sequence character in the end so when printing the array, stuff inside the memory after the array also gets printed. Why flushing the output buffer showing a different behaviour?

Also, since the 3rd example is printing garbage data at the end inspite of flusing the output buffer. How is the 3rd example different from 2nd?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, since character string literals, when used like this, must be `\0` terminated. Your compiler is free to produce a program that has any random result. Welcome to C++!

Comment: thats why I dislike the term "garbage". ppl expect to get soemthing that can be recognized as garbage, when in fact it is just undefined. Something that lookscompletely fine can be as "gargabe" as `HELLO@ ~`, you cannot reliably see the difference

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So, these undefined behaviours are compiler specific? If the program is not following the standard convention the compiler is free to produce any result? Also, I am a beginner, is there any online resource where I can learn about all these conventions in C++?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Oh, there are publishers that produce very bad stuff, and it doesn't even cost much these days if you only publish electronically (or even print on demand). You can make a lot of money from peddling books to those who can't tell that they are bad. (Even I have been approached about authoring by one of these publishers. They were basically churning out buzzword-compliant titles written by people who didn't mind, or didn't expect, not getting paid for their work.)

Comment: That's precisely the reason for the link that I provided in my previous comment.